# Is there a way to "forward" a Publisher through a Subject other than `sink`?

Tags: combine

I.e. something equivalent to

```swift
extension Publisher {
  func send(_ subject: some Subject<Output, Failure>) -> AnyCancellable {
    sink(
      receiveCompletion: subject.send,
      receiveValue: subject.send
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [subscribe(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/subscribe(_:)-3fk20) method which does that.

Here is an example:

```
private let originalSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
private let myRepublishingSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

originalSubject
   .subscribe(myRepublishingSubject)
   .store(in: &cancellables)
        
myRepublishingSubject
   .sink {
      print("Republished")
   }
   .store(in: &cancellables)

originalSubject.send()
```

Replace `originalSubject` with your publisher.

However, this is probably not the best way to use Combine in your code, because Subjects are mostly used as a glue between imperative code and Combine code. Why can't you use the original Publisher directly?

Comment: @Jessy the link I attached was referring to the wrong method. Fixed it and added an example to the original answer.

Comment: As for "why can't you use the original Publisher directly", [see here](https://forums.swift.org/t/what-is-the-correct-way-to-observe-the-changes-from-within-a-nested-observableobject/62788/4). Do you have a better solution than conforming `ObservableObject` to `Subject`?